# Построение графиков на основе отредактированного в python csv-файла

Tags: python, csv

Есть множество файлов в формате csv, с дробными значениями, примерно следующего формата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения эти отображают амплитуды колебания сигналов с платы в какой-то момент времени, где каждая строчка - это шаг. Графическое отображение раньше удавалось вполне успешно реализовывать средствами пайтона и его модулей, но, будучи в нем начинающим, наткнулся на определенные проблемы. Чтобы отобразить значения во времени, я добавил слева столбец, инкрементирующий на каждом шагу, символично отсчитывающий время. Сверху я добавил заголовки, для удобства отображения на графике столбцов в виде каналов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит результат так.
Но разнести значения каналов по времени у меня не выходит - в листинге видно, что наименования столбцов программа не считывает.

Использую Anaconda на базе 2.7 и Pyzo. Код ([на pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5q2NByPD)):

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import pandas as pd
from Tkinter import*
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
root=Tk()
root.fileName=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("csv files","*csv"),("All files","*.*" )))
k=root.fileName
print(k)
root.destroy()
pd.read_csv(k).mul(0.8).to_csv('minitest.csv', index=False)
 
with open('minitest.csv', 'rb') as input, open('temp.csv', 'w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')
 
    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.insert(0, '0')
    all.append(row)
    for k, row in enumerate(reader):
        all.append([str(k+1)] + row)
    writer.writerows(all)
 
with open('temp.csv','rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = [line for line in r]
with open('temp.csv','w') as f: 
    w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    w.writerow(['Time','CH1','CH2','CH3','CH4','CH5','CH6','CH7','CH8'])
    w.writerows(data)
    print(data)
 
my_data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv',sep=u',', header=0, skip_footer=0)
my_data.plot(x='Time',y=['CH1','CH2','CH3','CH4','CH5','CH6','CH7','CH8'],figsize=(14, 10))
plt.show()
```

Может кто-то подсказать, что мне в нем исправить для корректного отображения?

То, что получилось у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно то, что должно было быть (сделано средствами экселя)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас вопрос как Excel научить понимать ваш входной формат? (Он вероятно из-за десятичной точки на русской Винде глючит—просто пропишите, что точка это десятичная точка, а запятая это разделитель полей, а не разрядов). Или вы хотите средствами Питона рисовать? (Тогда [pandas и matplotlib можно использовать, чтобы временные ряды отобразить](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html))

Comment: Вы можете выложить где-нибудь пример входного файла в текстовом (CSV, TSV, etc.) формате (чтобы это можно было использовать в коде) и пояснить что за преобразования вы делали, чтобы получит `temp.csv` из `minitest.csv` (кроме добавления имен столбцов)?

Comment: Нет, эксель я использовал чтобы просто понять, как все должно выглядеть в результате. Осциллограф в принципе то же самое показывает, но скрины делать мой не умеет. Средствами питона хочу реализовать визуалку, использую и пандас и матплот, но результат вот как выше. Преобразования - умножил все значения на 0.8 (внутренний коэффициент усиления моей платы), и добавил столбец, отсчитывающий шаги, начиная с нуля (Time), который я хочу взять за Х при построении графика. Значения остальных столбцов за Y. Файлов входных много, но отличаются они только значениями - структура всегда остается одинаковой.

Comment: Два разных входных файла:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/iz88jcan80zfb35/1%D0%BB%D0%93%D1%860%2C5%D0%B2_All.csv

http://www.mediafire.com/download/4h7ota2v9dceuxb/1%D0%BB%D0%93%D1%860%2C5%D0%B2_7.csv

Comment: Вот так те же файлы выглядят в моей программе, которую я писал для осциллографа. То есть, отображение более-менее корректное.
http://s018.radikal.ru/i525/1609/b9/e12b15f78d70.png
И все, чем отличаются программы и файлы - csv файлы, которые пишет осциллограф, имеют внутренню индексацию столбцов (соответственно время и каналы) 
Именно поэтому я решил в обязательном порядке добавить заголовки - названия столбцов. Но программа их не считывает и не отображает, более того, они не отделяются запятыми на конце. Это получается другой формат данных внутри моего csv, навроде комментария, но не строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот что у меня получилось:

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_df(df, out_plot_fn=None, mult_factor=0.8,
            cols=None, x_axis=None, figsize=(12,10)):
    if x_axis:
        df = df.set_index(x_axis)

    if cols:
        df.columns = cols

    if mult_factor and mult_factor != 1:
        df *= mult_factor

    ax = df.plot.line(figsize=figsize)

    if out_plot_fn:
        plt.savefig(out_plot_fn)
    else:
        plt.show()


fn = r'D:\temp\.data\7.csv.gz'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, skipinitialspace=True)

plot_df(df, out_plot_fn=r'd:/temp/bad.png')


# пропускаем 7-ю колонку (Python/Pandas считают с нуля, поэтому - 6-ю)
# иначе по Y-axis будет неправильное масштабирование
# и все графики будут выглядеть слишком сглаженными 
usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,7]

df = pd.read_csv(fn, usecols=usecols, skipinitialspace=True)

plot_df(df, out_plot_fn=r'd:/temp/a.png')

# переименуем названия колонок в DF
cols = ['ch1','ch2','ch3','ch4','ch5','ch6','ch8']
plot_df(df, cols=cols, out_plot_fn=r'd:/temp/b.png')

# только первые 50 строк
plot_df(df.head(50), out_plot_fn=r'd:/temp/c.png')
```

### Результаты:

a.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

b.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

c.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что получается если не вырезать 7ю (`8`) и последнюю пустую (`Unnamed: 8`) колонку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С датафреймами я не решился связываться, но так код явно лучше структурно выглядит. Не посоветуете какой-нибудь мануал именно по работе с массивами данных и их визуализации? Второй раз уже меня выручаете, за что большое спасибо. Только не дает покоя: откуда все же берется 9-я (unnamed) колонка?

Comment: По поводу визуализации обычных данных (не NumPy/Pandas/SciPy) не посоветую - я этим не интересовался, мне очень важна скорость обработки данных поэтому я стараюсь все делать при помощи "векторизированных" операций (Pandas/NumPy/etc.). Колонка `Unnamed: 8` уже присутствует в вашем CSV - я не знаю как вы его получили...

Comment: Если все же решитесь использовать Pandas, то [ссылка от @jfs](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566568/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-python-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/566844#comment741253_566568) - как раз то, что вам нужно

Comment: Что ж, спасибо еще раз. Колонка после выполнения моей программы получалась и оставалась в любых csv, ошибка с индексами какая-то.

Comment: @irvis, я похоже забыл указать, что моей программой удобнее пользоваться с __исходным__ файлом, а не с теми которые вы уже обработали (похоже что `UnnamedL 8` появляется после `pd.read_csv(k).mul(0.8).to_csv(...)`). Если выложите пример __исходного__ файла я смогу показать как это делается.. PS метод `pd.read_csv()` очень гибкий и мощный - если у вас не "битый" CSV то с помощью этого метода можно прочитать любой CSV (можно задать имена столбцов, если их нет, можнл пропустить строки в начале и в конце, и т.д. )

Comment: первый же из тех, что я выложил, без колонки этой, по ссылке на медиафайр.

Comment: я не понимаю алгоритма по которому вы получили второй файл из первого... Числа все совсем другого порядка...

Comment: `Unnamed: 8` - это результат последней запятой (после которой отсутствуют данные) в исходном файле. Это легко решается при помощи `usecols=[...]` параметра - посмотрите как я это сделал в моем примере

Comment: Да usecols правда оптимальнее намного, я пытался его применять и до, но были ошибки. Поэтому целью было зацепиться за названия столбцов при отображении.

Comment: Такой еще вопрос небольшой: все, что до строки "def plot_df(df, out_plot_fn=None, mult_factor=0.8," запускается с рабочего стола через pythonw, если добавлять эти строки и далее, запускается программа только через среду Spyder, все работает, но только не как отдельный скрипт. Не знаете, что это может быть? Более простенькие скрипты открываются без проблем, графика в самом спайдере настроена как нужно, вроде бы.

Comment: До этой строки у меня идет ткинтеровское окно диалоговое, с выбором директории файла.

Comment: @irvis, весь блок `def ...` и до `fn = r'...'` (не включая последнюю строку) надо выполнить целым куском - т.к. это одна процедура.

Comment: Так она одной процедурой и осталась же по сути

Comment: @irvis, предлагаю открыть новый вопрос с указанием полного `error traceback` - этот вопрос и так уже порядком перегружен

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.